# Ignore/Disable Environment Variables in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to configure MSBuild so it ignores environment variables (in order to ensure full control over the build process regardless of machine). I know Microsoft's SQLCMD is capable of this, however I've checked the [MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019) for invoking MSBuild and see no comparable option.

Is it possible to tell MSBuild to ignore environment variables, and if so how?

Comment: Are you saying you have an MSBuild project that would build properly if MSBuild was started with an empty environment block and want to prevent the possibility of it building improperly or differently when the environment block is not empty?

Comment: I'm saying that as I understand it, it's possible to set msbuild variables (say $(configuration) for example) via environment variables, and its also possible to do so unwittingly. So I'd like something like the -X switch in SQLCMD, which decouples your scripts variables and behavior from the environment. And yes, this is for the sake of maximizing the determinism of my builds.

Comment: You can start any process with an empty environment ([CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw)). But it's a bit more complicated than that. My MSBuild (14 on Windows) requires SystemDrive and SystemRoot be set in the environment. It then creates about 3 dozen properties, mostly from the Windows registry. And that's without any Import elements and/or tasks that might also need or attempt to read the environment and registry. Maybe remote builds in a Docker container would give you the degree of control you want..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that might be a good workaround if that feature request in Martin Ullrich's answer doesn't get implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing (MSBuild 16.0) does not yet have any way to opt out of environment variable use.

The feature request is tracked on GitHub: [#2713 Long term effort for getting off Environment variables (for reproducible builds)](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2713)

Comment: Thank you- my current client blocks github so I was never going to get that on my own!